# How to filter BooleanField in template in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am preparing a image gallery for my website using `Django` . I have basically a `Gallery Model Foreign Key` in my `Image Model`. I have a `BooleanField` in my `Image` model to make a cover photo.

What I need is to get True value for the one in between images.

```
{% for gallery in gallery_list %}
 <div class="grid-item {{ choices | random }}">
  <a href="#" data-background="{{gallery.images}}#howtofilter?#" data-rel="lightcase:gal" title="Image Caption"></a>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I checked the documents for custom filters trying to solve but I could not figure out. Can you help me ?

Thanks

Ps Edit: adding my models

```
    class Gallery(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=_("gallery_title"),help_text _("Enter the Gallery title"))

    class Image(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=_("image_title"),help_text _("Enter the Image title"))
        gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)
        is_cover_photo = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: Please show both models code.

Comment: Added my models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method in `Gallery` model to return you a cover image:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    # other fields
    def cover_image(self):
        return self.image_set.filter(is_cover_photo=True).first()
```

Then in template:

```
{% for gallery in gallery_list %}
    {% with cover=gallery.cover_image %}
        {% if cover %}
            {# do something with cover image #}
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Aamir how can I view the image ? <img src="{{gallery.get_cover_image}}" > shows image title. But "gallery.get_cover_image.url" does not work.

Comment: What is the image/file field name in your `Image` model?

Comment: Welcome! Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to keep complex logic like this outside of your templates to avoid them getting too complicated. Save it for the views and/or models!

Sounds like the best bet here would be to have a method on your `Gallery` model to get the `Image` that has the cover image. Something like:

```
class Gallery
    ...model fields...

    def get_cover_image(self):
         return self.images_set.filter(cover_photo=True).first()
```

Then in your template, assuming the `Image` model has a property like `url`:

```
{% for gallery in gallery_list %}
  <div class="grid-item {{ choices | random }}">
    <a href="#" data-background="{{gallery.get_cover_image.url}}" data-rel="lightcase:gal" title="Image Caption"></a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

To save lots of DB queries here you might need/want to use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to get all the `Image` objects you'll need to display the galleries, but that's a different question.

Comment: This is a little out of date now you've edited with your models, and Aamir Adnan has the same idea

Comment: <a href="{% url 'galleries:detail' slug=gallery.slug%}" data-background="{{gallery.get_cover_image.url}}" /> this does not show photo.. do you have any idea how to show. when I check source code it is not marked up. data-background="" shows empty.